# Android - Google Sign in not working after published in the PlayStore

Tags: android, firebase, console, sha1

Before publishing in the play store my google sign was working fine. I saw some questions here in stackoverflow, but none of them answered my question. I don't know why the login is not working anymore. (I'm using firebase).

I know it is due to the different SHA1 key , but the SHA1 from my **app** ( which is in realese mode (Build Variants) ) is the same SHA1 key from the **APIs & Credentials** and same with the SHA1 key from the **firebase**.

When I go to the Developer Console > App Signing there is no SHA1 key only some text and on the top is a box about how an owner of an account can accept the service

Comment: add signed key..

Comment: Where do I find a signed key , and where do i Input it in ?

Comment: @Destro I already signed an apk

Answer (score 0):

Try first to link your account from firebase to the one from google play. This will create a new SHA-1 certificate for your app linked to your google play upload.